# How to return a value from C# to Windows Command Prompt (CMD)

Tags: c#, cmd, return

I want to return a value (a string) from my C# program to cmd. How can I do this?

Comment: Uh, what type of project? Console, WinForms, WPF, etc.

Comment: I assume you tried `Console.WriteLine()`?

Comment: do you mean like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4582/Command-Line-Written-in-C

Comment: @IliaG I tried your suggestion earlier, but it didn't work but now it works. Thank you.

Comment: can you explain a bit more on how it should work?

Comment: If you mean accessing CMD from c#, then start voting for opening the question again !

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate of the question that was originally marked as such. However, it would be useful to include more information on what you have tried here. A quick note: It's not possible to 'return' a string value, but you can write anything you want to the console, which you can capture and direct as needed.